# VLOOKUP Returning Blank value if error

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am trying to get VLOOKUP to return a blank if an error is returned that should show #NA

I have tried multiple functions such as IF(ISNA....) as was done on Microsoft's website and most currently

=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP('Order Form'!B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,3,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP('Order Form'!B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,3,FALSE))

The vlookup: VLOOKUP('Order Form'!B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,3,FALSE) works by itself except that I get an NA which I wanted to change to a blank.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `IFNA` is not a function. Is it a typo? Otherwise it looks like it would work with `ISNA`. Also, note that you can use `IFERRor` in Excel 2007 and later, allowing you to skip the repeated `VLOOKUP`, although it will capture all errors, not just `#N/A`s.

Comment: IFNA is a function "Returns the value you specify if the expression resolves to #NA.."

http://postimg.org/image/u3t5cyq7z/

In any case I apologize a professor showed me the resolution, the page was locked down and would not allow special functions like I had. Thank you for the information on the IFERROR, however, as it did simplify my function!

Comment: Oh right. Excel 2013. Then I think the whole formula is just:`=IFNA(VLOOKUP('Order Form'!B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,3,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Wait, you can't use `IFNA`? What's the specialized function?

Comment: No type of IF function was being allowed at all, I am not quite sure why. My professor sent me a different excel document without those problems.

Answer (score 1):

With your help and my reading of the [Office.com IFNA page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/ifna-function-HA102753281.aspx), how about:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP('Order Form'!B27,'Delivery Calculator'!A14:C17,3,FALSE),"")
```